# Changing PowerShell 7.2.2 color scheme to the default PowerShell 5.1

Tags: powershell, colors

As you can see the image below on the left shows what my PowerShell 7.2.2 looks like and the image on its right shows what my PowerShell 5.1 looks like.

[image]

I want to brighten the colors of my PowerShell 7.2.2 so that it would look exactly like my PowerShell 5.1 but I can't seem to think of how. I've tried going to settings but there is no such option. Therefore, I would greatly appreciate it if someone could tell me how.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: @music2myear I've gone to the settings folder and inspected plenty files but couldn't find the one that allows me to manipulate PowerShell colors.

Comment: Did you research online whether you can manipulate colors in the default PS terminal? There are several terminals that support PS just fine that do offer theming.

Comment: @music2myear Yes, ofcourse. But I'm not looking for other terminals, otherwise I would just use the Windows Terminal which offers theming. I'm here asking this question because I'm curious and I'm wondering whether the PowerShell 7.2.2 terminal could be configured to look exactly like the PowerShell 5.1 terminal.

Comment: You say you went to Settings, but did you go to Properties? Also, you still haven't answered if you did any research. Because I searched a basic query about changing PowerShell terminal colors and found solutions right away.

Comment: @music2myear I have, actually. And nothing worked. I've tried changing the values on the `Colors` & `Terminal` tabs. And I've also tried using `Set-PSReadLineOption` but it seems like the yellow/blue on the PowerShell 7.2.2 terminal is just different from the yellow/blue on the PowerShell 5.1 terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the values outputted by the commands shown below:

[image]

by entering commands `$host.PrivateData.[element name] = "[color code/name]"`,
`$PSStyle.[element name] = "[color code/name]"` and `Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{ "[element name]"="[color code/name]"}` respectively.

For more about the above commands, see:

1. About $host.PrivateData: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-host?view=powershell-7.2#example-8-set-the-background-color-for-error-messages
2. About $PSStyle: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ansi_terminals?view=powershell-7.2#psstyle
3. About Set-PSReadLineOption: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlineoption?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Noted & updated.